# Finding $x$ coordinates on a rectangle if Rectangle $a$ was scaled up to Rectangle $b$

Tags: geometry

I wasn't too sure how to explain the question in the title so i drew up my problem that I am trying to solve:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh77y.jpg

Basically I choose a point on rectangle $A$ and then find where this point should be if I were to scale rectangle $A$ up to rectangle $B$'s size.

Sorry I had a bit of trouble explaining the problem, I'm just not sure how to go about this. If someone could just explain how this could be achieved that'd be great.

Comment: From the conspicuous numbers it looks like you're trying to do something with monitor sizes! But as for the question, I don't think it's well defined because it depends on how you scale it. If you expand it from the center, the point would move to $(512, 270)$, but if you start by expanding it from the bottom right corner, it wouldn't move at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a quick geometric sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QZ2J.jpg). I found the answer by using the similar triangles shown in the sketch. You can use the relationships between the lines as ratios of the height of the base of the triangle to the total height and length of the side to the total length, and then apply the same ratios to the new triangle.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm just wondering if there is some sort of formula I could use to get the final result?

Comment: Well, in general, you can use the ratios like I mentioned. If you have another point to try, just construct the triangle and find the relationship between the total height, the height of the center, and the height of the point, and do the same for the new center.

Comment: Ah thanks for this, makes sense. Worked for me very well :)